# How do I set the ulimit in a nix build shell?

Tags: darwin, ulimit, nix

I am attempting to install the certbot package for nix, and it fails during the tests every time because the tests hit the open file limit on the system. I have modified the certbot install script just enough to print out the ulimit at the beginning of the `patchPhase` and find that the maximum number of allowed open files is 256. However, in the shell from which I am executing `nix-shell` or `nix-env`, my `ulimit` (both hard and soft) is set to 100000.

How can I propogate that limit down to the certbot build process? I would like to avoid trying to figure out how to modify the python build script that certbot uses.

Running a Bash shell on OSX 10.13.

Comment: Are you running the build on `nix-daemon` or do you have a single-user Nix installation?

Comment: Looks like `nix-daemon`. That would explain why things are not propogating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually raise the ulimit in the `patchPhase` stanza of `certbot.nix`. Turns out that this change propogates through the rest of the phases in the certbot build script.

```
  buildInputs = [ dialog ] ++ (with python2Packages; [ nose mock gnureadline ]);

  patchPhase = ''
    ulimit -n 8196
    substituteInPlace certbot/notify.py --replace "/usr/sbin/sendmail" "/run/wrappers/bin/sendmail"
    substituteInPlace certbot/util.py --replace "sw_vers" "/usr/bin/sw_vers"
  '';

  postInstall = ''
```

I will submit a patch to `nixpkgs`.

Comment: The phases are called from the same shell. `ulimit` is a shell built-in that sets process settings that are inherited by the child processes.